# AssetFinda Plugin projection issues in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

I am currently trying to overlay raster and vector data in a common projection as the Asset data which is using NZGD:2000 EPSG:2193. I have an ecw aerial image that initially loads as a generated CRS. There are also parcels and road vector data. I reprojected the vector layers using the 'save as' method and I reporjected the ecw image using the wrap tool. They I then load them into a new map project. I set the CRS for the map project to be epsg:2193 I also enable on the fly project. After that I load up the AssetFinda layers(which are sourced from an Sqllite.db generated from view tables from a SQL database) and unfortunately they still don't overlay with the other layers.

I had a thought that perhaps they are in the same projection but have different extents. However, they should have the same extent. Basically I have tried all the standard reprojection techniques and I was hoping someone here can think of something I may have overlooked.

Comment: Are you sure that your layers are initially loaded with the correct CRS? If QGIS thinks they're a different CRS than they actually are, reprojecting will be calculated based on the incorrectly specified CRS.

Comment: I assume you mean the layers I use for reference when editing the asset layers, parcels, roads, and aerials etc.

Comment: Have you tried loading the asset data in EPSG:2193 instead of in the user-generated CRS?